# How to export insert statements in Snowflake UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I get an export of `insert` statements in the Snowflake UI, like what I can get in SQL Developer. There is an option to get data in .csv and .tsv format, but not as `insert` statements.

Comment: Strg+C and save manually in .sql (or others) file?

Comment: i need insert statements to migrate data in higher env.

Comment: Snowflake wont export as insert statements automatically from what I understand. You need to use a tool like SQL Developer, DBeaver, Datagrip. They'll do it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use external tool that supports export to SQL

Example: [DBeaver - Data transfer](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Data-transfer/)

- Table/View in object explorer: RC -> Export Data -> SQL
- Results: RC -> Export Results -> SQL

[image]