# Snowflake create values for insert query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dml

Is it possible in SF to get data from one table in the format that I may use for inserting in another (new) table, for instance:

```
insert into new_table values 
(5, '2020-04-02 15:05:15.400','2020-04-03 15:14:30.400', 3),
(6, '2020-04-02 17:07:16.300','2020-04-02 19:10:15.400', 4),
(7, '2020-04-03 15:05:45.127','2020-04-04 18:05:15.400', 2);
```

I wouldn't use `insert ...select` syntax (or populate using csv/tsv).

Comment: And why wouldn't you use `insert . . . select`?

Comment: I don't have access to this table (in different cloud platform). Also tables are quite small.

Comment: . . If you don't have access to the table, how do you expect to see any data in it?

Comment: It is better to say i have access but tables are on different cloud platforms

Comment: @VladAleshin [Export as INSERT for instance using DBeaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67240423/5070879)

Answer (score 0):

In snowflake , as far as I know you need to make `external table`.

External tables reference data files located in a cloud storage (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure) data lake.

read more about it here: [Working with External Tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external.html)