# How to get a script of existing table in snowflake?

Tags: get, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl

I have an existing table in Snowflake. I need to get a script how this table was created.

I tried `get_ddl('Table', 'way to a table')` function. But this function helps me to get only the structure of a table in that way:

```
 create or replace TABLE BOOKS_TABLE (                                       |
|   ID NUMBER(38,0),                                                      |
|   TITLE VARCHAR(255),                                                   |
|   AUTHOR VARCHAR(255)                                                   |
| );
```

I want to get a script `create table AS (SELECT * FROM table)` how that table was created

How can I solve it?

Comment: As get_ddl generates the CREATE statement for an object, I’m not clear what you mean by “script” and what you are trying to generate. Can you update your question with an example and/or further explanation, please?

Comment: @Denis It is vague what would you like to achieve. If you want to export INSERT INTO queries you could use external tool [how to export insert statements in snowflake UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67229997/how-to-export-insert-statements-in-snowflake-ui/67240423#67240423) though this approach is fine for small tables

Comment: @NickW made an update of my question

Answer (score 1):

You can check the query_history to locate the create table SQL command that was executed to create that table.

```
select * from snowflake.account_usage.query_history where query_text ilike '%create%table%books_table%';
```